# Prove that a series of numbers are random

Tags: random, pattern-recognition

I have a series of randomly generated numbers (3, 1,-3, 2, -1,6). I want to prove that the numbers are not random but have an increasing/decreasing pattern.

The source of the numbers isn't really important. I just want to prove that the numbers are truly random.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: How did you obtain these "randomly" generated numbers? What do you mean, specifically, by the word "random" here? For example, would the series $(1, -7)$ be random?

Comment: @TheoBendit (1,−7) is too short to determine a pattern.

Comment: @JohnGrant So, am I right in thinking a series of numbers is not random if it has a pattern?

Comment: @TheoBendit, Is there a way to prove an increasing or decreasing pattern

Comment: @JohnGrant Not really. Given any finite series of numbers, it is possible to produce infinitely many polynomial patterns that generate that series. In a sense, a no finite series of numbers is ever inherently "random".

Answer (score 0):

It is surprisingly hard to formally define random and hence hard to prove whether something is random or not.  For example, are the digits of $\pi$ random?  They pass pretty much any test or randomness yet they are predictable from one of the many ways of calculating $\pi$.

Finite sequences are particularly troublesome since it is easy to construct a formula that will generate any specified finite sequence.

One attractive way to say whether a sequence is random is whether the most compact way to specify it is to just list the values.  In his sense, the digits of $\pi$ fails since there are quite simple formulae which generate them.  Note that I am not claiming this as a standard definition just one that is sometimes appropriate.